# .htaccess RewriteCond (folder exists but still being passed to handler)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

So awhile ago I posted a question regarding .htaccess `Rewrite Conditions` and how I can achieve a more readable URL. Such that the URL would like something like so: `http://somedomain.com/variable/variable/variable/`

The `RewriteCond` worked perfectly but now I am noticing some repercussions. Subdirectories that are using `.htaccess` (in my case, I am using it for `AuthUser`) are ignored by the root `.htaccess` `RewriteCond` statement. I tried to specify the folder that contains the `.htaccess` but it is a hit or miss. On one computer, it works great and I can go to the URL just fine but on another, I cannot. What ultimately ends up happening is that the URL I tried to go to (in this case, "/pricing") ends up passing the variable (pricing) onto my index handler.

So without further ado, here it is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pricing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !index\.php                          [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/([^/]+)/?  [NC]
RewriteRule .  index.php?prefix=%1&month=%2&day=%3&title=%4    [L,NC]
```

Is there anything anyone suggests changing here? I mean, I don't understand how another `.htaccess` in a sub directory is causing this to happen.

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: When you request an url (e.g. `http://example.com/pricing/shoes`, it will consult the config files in `/pricing/shoes`, `/pricing`, `/` and the main config (httpd.conf), unless it encounters an `END` flag somewhere. Other than that, I am not really understanding the question (might be just me).

Answer (score 0):

The way you have structured your rules it not going to work since captured variables are available from most recent RewriteCond only.

You can do this instead:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pricing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]*)(?:/([^/]*)(?:/([^/]*))?)?)?/?$ index.php?prefix=%1&month=%2&day=%3&title=%4  [QSA,L]
```